# Base64 PDF file view In Touch-enabled PDF view in jquery

Tags: php, pdf

I am Using Touch enabled PDF to view PDF file . Now I am in trouble i have only a base64 encoded PDF but i can't able to render that pdf in the Touch -enabled PDF viewer (pdf.js).

```
 $(function() {
    $("#myPDF").pdf( {
        source: url+"/"+pdffile,
        title: pdffile,

    } );
});
```

Here In the Place of source I need to read that base64 encoded string.

My target is to view a PDF in the web using base64 encoded and I have done this by

```
$data = base64_decode($encodedData);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
echo $data;
exit;
```

It will Show the PDF. but I need to prevent the download option for that PDF.

Please help me do touch- enabled pdf view using base64 encoded pdf or help me to disable the download option for pdf view in browser.

Comment: You cannot, at the same time, view a file, and disable its download. The best you can do is make it slightly harder to download it.

Comment: not like that i don't want to download link should be disable in the browser

Comment: <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo $pdfdata; ?>#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="1028"></iframe> is this will help to disable the download option?